# I want to open a new window when clicking the button with actionperformed

Tags: java

When the button is clicked with `actionPerformed`, I want to open a new window, but I cannot open whatever I type. Can you support?
I tried that:

```
JButton btnNewButton_5 = new JButton("Place Order");

btnNewButton_5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) (
        new Final().setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Abra I think `Final` class extends `JFrame` that's why he/she didn't get a compile-time error by calling `setVisible()` method.

Comment: It's a final form. i created it and i'm trying to make it open

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to set the size and/or dimension of your new window. I think the new window has been opened but it is not visible to you. I think you should replace your code like this

```
    JButton btnNewButton_5 = new JButton ("Place Order");
    
    btnNewButton_5.addActionListener (new ActionListener () (
    
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) (
        Final final = new Final();
        final.setSize(500,500);
        final.setVisible (true);
      }
    });
```

Comment: I created a new form called final with swing I want to call it